# how to solve this hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I didn't understand how to solve this problem from the beginning. I tried to establish the parameters for example, but I don't know if I did it correctly and applied the right formula

In a certain online search system, the time to complete searches is approximately normal, with a mean of 55 seconds and a standard deviation of 16 seconds. Some modifications were applied to the system and it was observed, in 35 searches, that the average time reduced to 43 seconds. Is there evidence of improvement? Assume that the 35 observations are random samples.

(a) Set the variables and parameters
(b) Establish the null (H0) and alternative (H1) hypotheses.
(c) Carry out a test for the hypotheses in (b) at the 0.05 significance level. (Build a critical region and make a decision)

Comment: This seems to be a textbook problem, requiring a 'Self-Study' tag. Please say what formula you are trying to use, and what values are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comment:* If you were willing to make the (seemingly altogether unwarranted) assumption that the $35$ searches after modifications are from a normal population with $\sigma=16$ (unchanged by modifications), then you could do a z test of $H_0: \mu = 55$ vs. $H_a: \mu < 55.$

You would get test statistic $Z = -4.44$ and very small P-value (`0.000` means $< 0.0005),$ rejecting $H_0$ in favor of $H_a,$ and concluding the modifications successfully reduced average search time.

Output from the z-test procedure in Minitab (which accepts
summarized data) is shown below:

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 55 vs < 55
The assumed standard deviation = 16

 N   Mean  SE Mean  95% Upper Bound      Z      P
35  43.00     2.70            47.45  -4.44  0.000
```

(I am not calling this an "answer" because I don't believe it---and neither should you.)

One way to do a realistic test would require you to use the sample SD of the 35 post-modification searches. (Another would require you to know the
post-modification population standard deviation.)